# Invite Facebook users at first launch

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

I'm considering developing an app that asks users to invite friends to participate at first launch, using the Request dialog. (The Request dialog would have a prominent Skip button, in agreement with Facebook policy IV.4.)

Browsing this forum, it appears that there USED to be a "Developer Policy V.4" which, at one time, said this: "You must not prompt users to send invitations, requests, generate notifications, or use other Facebook communication channels immediately after a user allows access or returns to your application."

I no longer see language like that in the policies available here: http://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Does this mean that prompting users to send invitations at first launch is now allowed? Or am I simply overlooking some language in the new policies that forbids this?

Comment: I also posted this question on [Facebook's forums](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=355714#p355714). No reply.

Comment: Good luck getting any answers on the Dev Forums. My advice? Go for it and hope for the best. (Good luck!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this was removed intentionally, as it clearly isn't in their updated developer policies.  The only mention of that old policy I can find is [here](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=57725).  That post also gives a good reasoning for the old policy:

> When a user -- whether returning or
>   new -- visits your application, you
>   must allow the user to engage with
>   your application before asking him/her
>   to publish a stream story, send out
>   Requests, or use any other
>   communication channel. The intention
>   behind this policy is to give users
>   the opportunity to meaningfully
>   interact with an application before
>   being faced with the decision of
>   whether to communicate with friends.

The advice is still valid even if the policy is no longer in place - that you should give the user a chance to use and learn about your application before being prompted to share it.  However, if you are building a game like Words With Friends where you need to play against one of your Facebook friends, then I think it would be fine (almost necessary) to invite friends right away, and this may be why Facebook removed this from their policy.

I think you will be fine if you prompt a user to send friend invites immediately, provided its not for the purpose of spamming other people to get them to use your app and that you provide a skip option.

Also, its sad that its near impossible to get a response from Facebook like you have seen with their forums.